# How to play a background audio in website for all page?

Tags: javascript, avaudioplayer

I want to use background audio for all pages of the website but it shouldn't be started from the beginning if I refresh the page or redirect to another page. currently, I'm using this code

```
window.onload = function() {
   var audio = new Audio('/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/shai-baba-chant.mp3');
audio.play();
}
```

It's working fine but there is the issue that if I refresh the page or go to another page it starts from the beginning. Is there any way to push and resume the audio after page load again?

Comment: Listen to [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) event. Store the `currentTime` in localStorage. Read the value on page refresh and update the `currentTime` property of the audio element.

Comment: Do remember that MANY people (myself included) absolutely hate background audio on a web page.  It's a disaster in an office environment.  Don't start it unless they ask for it.

Comment: you cannot do audio.play() on window.onload. browser does not let you autoplay audio. user has to interact with it first.

Comment: What browser are you using? I do not see how this can possibly work on many current browsers - for example on Edge I get 'play failed because the user didn't interact with the document first' - so there will be a break in the playing waiting for them to e.g. click something to cause the play.even if you have remembered (roughly) where it left off.